Redistributing flow in a network
Suppose I have a maximum flow problem from a source $s$ to a sink $t$, where $c_{u,v}$ are given:
\begin{align*}
\max & \sum_{v: (s,v) \in E} f_{s,v}\\
\text{s.t.} & \sum_{u:(u,v) \in E} f_{u,v} = \sum_{w: (v,w) \in E} f_{v,w}, \quad \forall v \in V-\{s,t\}\\
& c_{u,v}\geq f_{u,v}\geq 0
\end{align*}
Now, suppose I have an optimal solution $f^*$ such that there exists a solution such that $f^*_{u,v} = c_{u,v}$ for some edge $(u,v)$. Furthermore, suppose I cannot push more flow across the network without affecting feasibility (see image below).
Is it true, that in every other optimal solution $\hat{f}$, $\hat{f}_{u,v} = c_{u,v}$?
My try: I wanted to prove that if I try to lower $f^*_{u,v}$, then any other solution has a lower objective. Is it true that I can 'get' from $f^*$ to $\hat{f}$ by moving flow? I tried to make a drawing, and it seems that no matter what, if the red edges are completely used $(f^*_{u,v} = c_{u,v})$, then any optimal solution needs to completely use the red edges. Is this a well-known result?
The white circumferences below represent clusters of connected nodes, so that there are many edges going out from clusters to clusters but in the end the optimal solution $f^*$ completely uses the red edges.

